# How to Identify and remove tables Which are not being used in my mvc project

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, model-view-controller

There are lots of table in my SQL Server Database. Many other Developers worked on the project and created these tables Which are not being used, after changes in requirments. Now we need to refine our code as well as database schema for better perfomance and optimization.

Is there any automated way to identify and remove redundant unused tables from project source code?

Comment: Are you using EntityFramework to connect to the database and perform the database operations?

Comment: Did you look at the xml config file which is ascii?

Comment: Thanks @ChetanRanpariya for a quick reply, yes I'm using entityFramework DB First approach.

Comment: No @jdweng. I didn't looking for such kind ov things.

Comment: You should first figure your business requirement and understand how many and which tables of the database are needed for the it. List down the table names which are not needed and then remove then from the database and then update the EF Model in the project.

Comment: Infact I was searching for a tool or an automated way to do so.